# Flutter: Bloc not emmiting events (working minimal example)

Tags: flutter, bloc

Could I ask for assistance for this problem? My CombosBloc does not receive the CategoryChangedEvent.

1. The Bloc is create on main with `BlocProvider(create: (_) => CombosBloc(), lazy: false)`
2. On the TaskPage, which is a few clicks away from the Home, I construct another page, let's called EditPage, inherited from TaskPage, by clicking in a button. In the initState of the EditPage, I try to emit an event like this: `context.read<CombosBloc>().add(CategoryChangedEvent(newCategory: widget.task!['category']));`
3. Passed event 2, when the initState ends, starts the building process for the widgets of the EditPage. Inside those widgets, there is a **DropdownButtonHideUnderline**, which in it's own initState, tries to read a value from the CombosBloc like this: `selected = context.read<CombosBloc>().state.category;` The value read is empty, which causes a crash. I have checked that the value in **'widget.task!['category']'** is valid in step 2.
4. Weirdly enough, the behavior's above happens when I debug the app. When I ran without debugging, only then, I see this change on the console from the Observer I created: `CombosBloc Change { currentState: CombosInitial(, Todas, Mais recentes, false), nextState: CombosState(Estudos, Todas, Mais recentes, false) }`. This gets printed only after all 9885 StackTraces messages in the console.

My minimal working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  Bloc.observer = const Observer();
  runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => CombosBloc(), lazy: false),
    ], child: EntryPoint()),
  );
}

class Observer extends BlocObserver {
  const Observer();
  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase<dynamic> bloc, Change<dynamic> change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print('${bloc.runtimeType} $change');
  }
}

class AppRouter {
  final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/',
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
          name: 'home',
          path: '/',
          builder: (context, state) => const FirstPage()),
    ],
  );
}

class EntryPoint extends StatelessWidget {
  EntryPoint({super.key});

  final _appRouter = AppRouter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Testing',
      routerConfig: _appRouter.router,
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<FirstPage> createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Testing')),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          child: const Text('Click me!'),
          onPressed: () async {
            await Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const SecondPage(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SecondPage> createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    context
        .read<CombosBloc>()
        .add(const CategoryChangedEvent(newCategory: 'testing'));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Second Page')),
      body: const Center(
        child: Combo(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Combo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Combo({super.key});

  @override
  State<Combo> createState() => _ComboState();
}

class _ComboState extends State<Combo> {
  final List<String> values = ['1', '2', '3'];
  late String selected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    selected = context.read<CombosBloc>().state.category;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
        border: Border.all(),
      ),
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
          value: selected,
          iconSize: 28,
          isExpanded: true,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward_sharp),
          elevation: 16,
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {},
          items: values.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                value,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              )),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// ---------- BLOC ------------ ///

class CombosBloc extends Bloc<CombosEvent, CombosState> {
  CombosBloc() : super(const CombosInitial()) {
    on<CategoryChangedEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(state.copyWith(category: event.newCategory));
    });
  }
}

sealed class CombosEvent extends Equatable {
  const CombosEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class CategoryChangedEvent extends CombosEvent {
  const CategoryChangedEvent({required this.newCategory});
  final String newCategory;
}

final class CombosState extends Equatable {
  const CombosState({
    required this.category,
  });

  final String category;

  CombosState copyWith({
    String? category,
  }) {
    return CombosState(
      category: category ?? this.category,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [category];
}

final class CombosInitial extends CombosState {
  const CombosInitial() : super(category: '');
}
```

Comment: can you add the widget code? just to check how are you updating the event and how are you creating/listening the bloc

Comment: @diegoveloper Done it. :)

Comment: check my answer, let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An angel told me the answer. :D

It seems the add(SomeEvent) of the Bloc is not synchronous, so, by the time my `DropdownButton` was being created, the value hasn't been updated yet. I solved by changing into Cubit and managing the value using getters and setters. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

double check that the widget where you are dispatching the CategoryChangedEvent has access to the CombosBloc. You mentioned using context.read(), which is correct. Ensure that the context is associated with the BlocProvider where the CombosBloc is provided.

Example:

```
context.read<CombosBloc>().add(CategoryChangedEvent(newCategory: 'your_category'));
```

Comment: Well, I'm not receiving any errors about this. I create this bloc in the main, so it will be available to my entire app.

Answer (score 0):

The event probably is not triggered because you are calling the event in the `initState` method, where the widgets are not attached yet and the builder is not listening.

So just make sure your widget is attached and listening using this code in your initState method.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((Duration duration) {
    if (widget.isEditing) {
      title = 'Editar tarefa';
      _nameController.text = widget.task!['name'];
      _descController.text = widget.task!['desc'];
      print("widget.task!['category']: ${widget.task!['category']}");
      context
          .read<CombosBloc>()
          .add(CategoryChangedEvent(newCategory: widget.task!['category']));
    }
  });

  super.initState();
}
```

Also, I noticed you forgot the prop implementations of your events (with params).

```dart
final class CategoryChangedEvent extends CombosEvent {
  /// Default constructor.
  const CategoryChangedEvent({required this.newCategory});

  /// New value.
  final String newCategory;

@override
  List<Object> get props => [newCategory];
}
```

Comment: That didnt solved it, but thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: can you add the widget you use to listen the bloc please? also, are you seeing this log?  print('OnEvent: ${event.newCategory}');

Comment: I updated the code. I don't see the print event, so it does not get called at all!

Comment: Check my updated answer :)

Comment: Nothing changed. :( I added a minimal working example in my original post.

Comment: so if you print something  above: emit(state.copyWith(category: event.newCategory)); , with the "event.newCategory", nothing happens? did you update the `CategoryChangedEvent` with the code I provided?

Comment: Yes, nothing happens. I tried your code too. I updated my original post with a minimal working example with the problem. You can teste there, too, if you want.

Comment: I don't see your code using the code I added, update your question

Comment: also, it would be great if you can create a repo with this code/project to download and test, otherwise we'll need to create a new project add all the dependencies at that will take time